# Как двоичный код из Sql server преобразовать в формат Xps в Wpf?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server

```
<Grid>
        <FlowDocumentReader x:Name="rishTextBox">
        <FlowDocument  ColumnWidth="150" ColumnGap="10">
            <BlockUIContainer>

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElectronicVersion}"/>
            </BlockUIContainer>

            </FlowDocument>
        </FlowDocumentReader>
                    
    
</Grid>
```

Какой бы элемент не использовал для привязки результат всегда один.

Или выводит надпись **Byte[] Array** или нечего не выводит (

Я сделал вот так

```
<Grid Height="auto" Width="auto" x:Name="gridDate">
    <TextBlock VerticalAlignment="Bottom" x:Name="textBlock"
                        TextWrapping="Wrap" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        Margin="0 0 30 5" FontSize="14"
                        Text="{Binding ElectronicVersion}"/>
    <StackPanel>
        <UniformGrid Rows="1">


            <Button Content="Xps File to Bytes Array" HorizontalAlignment="Left"   x:Name="btnOpenFile" Click="btnOpenFile_Click"/>
            <Button Content="Show Array" Margin="10"  x:Name="btnShowArray" Click="btnShowArray_Click"/>

        </UniformGrid>
        <DocumentViewer Height="500"  x:Name="doc"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

public test()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        gridDate.DataContext = App.DataBase.Books.ToArray();
    }
    
    private void btnShowArray_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {          
        MemoryStream docStream = new MemoryStream(Convert.ToInt32(textBlock.Text));
        Package package = Package.Open(docStream);

        
        string inMemoryPackageName = string.Format("memorystream://{0}.xps", Guid.NewGuid());
        Uri packageUri = new Uri(inMemoryPackageName);

       
        PackageStore.AddPackage(packageUri, package);

        XpsDocument xpsDoc = new XpsDocument(package, CompressionOption.Maximum, inMemoryPackageName);
        FixedDocumentSequence fixedDocumentSequence = xpsDoc.GetFixedDocumentSequence();
                   
        doc.Document = fixedDocumentSequence;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В гриде передаю данные через DataContext,   TextBlock подхватывает судя по всему эти данные.

Пытаюсь содержимое текст блока передать в кнопку что бы отобразил в DocumentViewer,  но выдаёт исключение
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что сможете так просто взять байты и перевести его в документ? Вам надо сначала открыть `MemoryStream` из этих байт, затем сделать `Package` (`System.IO.Packaging.Package.Open(memoryStream);`, затем, делать `XpsDocument` передав туда пакет, затем вы должны подготовить `FixedDocumentSequence`, вызвав `GetFixedDocumentSequence()` у `XpsDocument`. И вот когда вы это все проделаете, когда у вас на руках будет готовый `FixedDocumentSequence`, тогда уже можете пробовать выводить, например так `<DocumentViewer Document="{Binding Document}"/>`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну просто когда я биндил картинку такого же типа byte, он нормально отображал. Вот и подумал что с документом возможно также будет

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, я добавил код, что не так делаю ?

Comment: Прочитайте еще раз, внимательней то, что я вам написал, а именно `открыть MemoryStream из этих байт`, почему у вас вдруг появляется string (`textBlock.Text`), из которой вы пытаетесь сделать число и затем это число превратить в поток, ну подумайте просто логически, это вообще как должно работать?

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, ну по поводу числа, я там все типы данных перепробовал, результат везде один. Пока я в текст блок данные массива заношу (это вроде не принципиально куда заносить)

Comment: Почему это не принципиально. Если вы в мясорубку засунете кусок говядины, на выходе будет кусок говядины, или будет фарш из этого куска? Также и тут, у вас есть (как я понял) в базе `byte[]`, то есть, массив байт, вы непойми зачем его суете в контрол, а тот на выход вам дает `string` (скорей всего просто описание типа (`System.Byte[]` или нечто подобное), затем вы это пытаетесь привести к числу (является ли строка, в которой текст `"System.Byte[]"` числом?). В итоге получается, что вы из простого текста `"System.Byte[]"` хотите получить XPS документ.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, а как правильно должно быть 

Comment: Я вам самым первым комментарием написал как, не городите лишнего и будет вам счастье, если что не понимаете, то поиском легко находится все это. Еще раз повторю `открыть MemoryStream из этих байт`, то есть, `new MemoryStream(массив байт)`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ, понял спасибо. Сейчас я понял что фигня записывается а не массив, буду искать дальше как получить значение массива